# Molecular symmetry point group being expressed as a direct produt

Tags: symmetry, group-theory

For the case of a molecule like Ammonia, we know that it has a $3$-fold rotation axis, the group being $C_3=\{e,a,a^2\}$, and we can have a vertical plane of reflection that has the axis of rotation, and the plane passes through the nitrogen and a hydrogen atom, the group being $\sigma_v=\{E, b\}$. Both the groups here are cyclic being of order $3$ and $2$ respectively. Now, can we express the complete point group $P$ of the molecule's symmetry as $P=C_3\times \sigma_v$ i.e. the direct product of the groups? And if we can, what are the equivalence class of the group $P$?

In a set of lectures I am learning the material from, the lecturer uses some weird way of writing direct products in which the entire ordered pair structure is dropped and then it is claimed that the equivalence class classification of the group P is $P=\{e\} \cup \{a,a^2\}\cup\{b,ab,a^2b\}$. I am trying to obtain the same result from the ordered pair structure of the direct products and it is not working out at all.

P.S.: The definition of direct product I am considering is the one given here: [Wiki definition of Direct Product of Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Definition)

Comment: [Here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/11%3A_Molecules/11%3A_Molecular_Symmetry).

Comment: Think of the direct product as a 2x3 matrix, and *b* as "parity", which cannot be undone by equivalence. All odd parity elements are in the last class, the second line of your matrix. The first line breaks up into the identity and then the rest, as in your lectures. It is not "weird". It is mainstream. Try a Book!

Comment: @CosmasZachosThanks for the comment, but it still doesn't answer my question. whether is the total point group of symmetry just a direct product of each constituent symmetry?  I am getting an intuition that it isn't because the direct product group for ammonia wasn't isomorphic to the point group $P$.

Comment: Did you explain why?